# Configure log files for specific application in Weblogic

Tags: jakarta-ee, log4j, weblogic, weblogic11g

I am using Weblogic 11g, EJB3.0.

I am struggling for weeks with this problem.

I have several deployments(Stateless beans).

each one has it's own log4j jar (log4j-1.2.15.jar) and each one has it's own log4j.properties.

problem is: when the I write to log(debug/error/info etc.) all logs from all deployments are written to the **same log file**.

this is annoying since I want **each** deployment to write to it's **own** and **only** log file (which configured in it's log4j.properties)

this is my log4j.properties file:

> log4j.rootCategory=debug, R
>
> log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
>
> ## the next line has different path+name in each project.

log4j.appender.R.File=D\:\bea11\user_projects\domains\base_domain\autodeploy\MyProject\logs\MyProject.log

> log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=8192KB
>
> log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=100
>
> log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>
> log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd
>   MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %p %m%n
>
> log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info
>
> log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
>
> log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=info
>
> log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=info
>
> log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=info

my project is divided to three dependencies in Myeclipse:

ProjectName

ProjectNameEJB

ProjectnameWeb

and I have installed in in Weblogic as Exploded Archive

the jar is located under this dir path: ProjectName/ear/app-inf/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar

and log4j.properties located under the root dir: ProjectName/log4j.properties

Thanks,
ray

Comment: Is `MyProject.log` the same hardcoded string in all the properties? or do you change it to the actual name of the Project in each file?

Comment: I change it to the actual name of the project in each file.

Comment: I suspect your log4j settings are being over-ridden somewhere else. Can you try changing the `ConversionPattern` for any one app and see does that reflect into your single log file? Is there any log4j setting being passed into the startCommand ?

Comment: in the end the prob was with my dir names, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

must locate the properties.xml under app-inf/classes

and the the log4j.jar under app-inf/lib

and make sure you dont have the log4j.jar under the server/lib dir.

Answer (score 0):

@rayman: you need to check first what is classloading policy of your project in weblogic console...if they are sharing same classloader for Logger class (as class is unique per classloader), then it is going to use same instance of logger using same configuration...
...you can also print file location used by logger by calling below in each of your application at some point:-

```
((org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender)org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("R") ).getFile()
```

Comment: My answer to this question did the trick easly.. thanks for your comment.